# What does var or var equals to mean in php?

Tags: php

Could anyone give me explanation about the following code?

```
$var OR $var = $something;
```

Googled a lot, but couldn't find anything relevant.

Why is OR on the left side instead of javascript's syntax on the right side? Are they the same, or is there any difference?

Comment: Means nothing after php reads this line `$var` still has his old value and `$something` has his old value.

Comment: This question is not too broad (it is asking about a single line of code) nor is it asking for any recommendations.

Comment: I would recommend you to add what you have found/read and what did helped or not helped you. Also add if you want to ask why the OR is on the left side! So you show some research/work and you add a bit of *value* with this to your question

Comment: haven't found anything useful, that's why I asked it here :) as @watcher said it wasn't too broad as I think, but even if it was, now that I've updated it, isn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tldr;** This is basically just an initialization step and ensures the variable `$var` holds *some* value that is not falsey.  In English it is saying the following:

> Evaluate the value stored in `$var`.  If it is truthy, great stop right there.  Otherwise, set `$var` equal to `$something`.

**How it works**

This takes advantage of the short-circuiting nature of OR, as mentioned in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php):

```
// foo() will never get called as those operators are short-circuit

$a = (false && foo());
$b = (true  || foo());
$c = (false and foo());
$d = (true  or  foo());
```

While I find this is common in JavaScript, I rarely see this type of code in PHP.  I believe this has to do with the fact that, in JavaScript, you can call a function without having to pass any of the named parameters in:

```
function testFn(param1, param2) {
    param1 = param1 || 'default value';
    param2 = param2 || 'default param2 value';
}
testFn();
testFn(12);
testFn(12, 13);
```

All three of those function calls are legal.  The first one will set the parameters to their `'default ...'` values.  The second one will set the first parameter to `12` and the second one to `'default param2 value'`, and the third one will set the first parameter to 12 and the second parameter to 13.

In PHP you can also, but you have to supply default values for the variables in the function signature or it will result in a `PHP Warning:  Missing argument 1 for ...`:

```
function testFn($param1 = 'default1', $param2 = 'default2') { }
testFn();
testFn(12);
testFn(12, 13);
```

Setting the default parameters via the function's signature to me seems a much more readable way of doing it.

**Long-winded Concrete Example**

Consider this statement:

```
if(false && functionThatReturnsTrue()) {}
```

Clearly this cannot ever be true overall, but the important point here is that `functionThatReturnsTrue` never gets called.  Now, I can pull out that entire conditional to make a brand-new, completely legal statement:

```
false && functionThatReturnsTrue();
```

Still, `functionThatReturnsTrue` is not getting called.  If I change the `&&` to an `||`, though, it will:

```
function functionThatReturnsTrue() {
    echo "I'm true!";
}

false || functionThatReturnsTrue();
```

Above, notice that `functionThatReturnsTrue` doesn't even return anything! the entire expression above *will be evaluated* (it will evaluate overall to `false`), but *will not be stored* anywhere.  Also note that the function *will be called* and `"I'm true!"` will be displayed on the screen.

Now let's replace `functionThatReturnsTrue` with a variable assignment:

```
false || $var = 12;
```

Here, there will be three expressions that will be evaluated: `false` (which has no side-effects), `$var = 12` (which will set `$var` equal to 12), and the *overall* expression `false || 12` (because the result of assigning a value to a variable is the value being assigned, which is why you can also do things like `return $var = 12;`).  After that line of code executes, `$var` will be equal to 12.

Let's now replace that first `false` with your `$var`:

```
$var || $var = 12;
```

If `$var` happens to be anything other than `null`, `false`, 0, or `''` ([anything that can evaluate to `false`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)), then the expression `$var = 12` *will not be executed*, and `$var` will have the same value it had before this line ran.  If it is falsey, however, then it will no longer equal whatever it was, it will now equal 12.

Let's take one more step and make it just a tad bit more complicated:

```
$whatAmI = ($var || $var = 12);
```

Here, I took the previous expression, wrapped it in parentheses, and I am actually keeping it's result inside a variable named `$whatAmI` rather than just throwing it into the bit bucket.  `$whatAmI` will be a `boolean` value (because it is holding the result of the `||` operation) and there could have been two side effects to this line being executed:

1. `$var` *may* have been updated to the value 12
2. `$whatAmI` will now be holding a boolean value of `true`

Comment: okay, but why is "OR" on the left side, not on the right side?

Comment: @KissKoppány Maybe a chinese programmer wrote it and he wrote from right to left :D

Comment: @KissKoppány I elaborated a bit, see my update

Comment: haha perhaps you're right :D